# Why wont these find and update mongo db calls work in the right sequence?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am working on a function that takes in student data from an excel sheet and assigns the students to student-groups based on the data in the student's row.

I am having problems getting it to accumulate all the imported students, instead it only seems to write the last one or two students if I import a batch of three students.

There are three steps as I see it: I need to find the current student list for a group, then add the new student to that list, and then finally update the group list with the old students and the new students combined.

I think there must be a race error happening because the 'found students' always console logs as an empty list, so the update part isn't happening in the right sequence I believe?

Here is the first way I tried it, which gave me the undesired result described:

```
global.db.collection("groups").find({userId: user_id.toString(), groupNumber:parseInt(realGroupNumber)}).toArray( function (err, group) {
    if(err) {console.log(err)};
    if(group[0]) {
        //Add student to group's student list...
        group[0].students.push(NewRow[realRowNumber]);
        //Update  group with new student list...
        global.db.collection("groups").updateOne({userId: user_id.toString(), groupNumber:parseInt(realGroupNumber)}, {$set: group[0]}, {upsert: true}, function (err, group) {
            if(err) {console.log(err)};
        });
    };
});
```

Then I tried to use a callback function to avoid a race error, but got the same result:

```
function findStudentList(param, callback) {
    //Find group matching group number, user id
    global.db.collection("groups").find({userId: user_id.toString(), groupNumber:parseInt(param)}).toArray( function (err, group) {
        if(err) {console.log(err)};
        if(group[0]) {
            callback(group[0]);
        };
    });
};

function updateStudentList(oldGroupInfo) {
    newStudent = NewRow[realRowNumber]
    oldGroupInfo.students.push(newStudent)
    // db.update with new list here
    global.db.collection("groups").updateOne({userId: user_id.toString(), groupNumber:parseInt(realGroupNumber)}, {$set: oldGroupInfo}, {upsert: true}, function (err, group) {
        if(err) {console.log(err)};
    });
};

findStudentList(realGroupNumber, updateStudentList)
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? This is inside a for loop, being called once per new student. It acts like previous update to the student list never happened... The find call comes up with an empty student list every time through, instead of adding and accumulating students. Even though I have console logged everything and the data is going to the right place, just not updating correctly. Once again only the last student or the last two students make it in the group successfully.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: can you share data ?

Comment: Okay I think I figured out what is wrong. The second database call to write the data fires off, but the for loop doesn't wait for this call to finish before continuing to start over the loop. So when it finds data again on the second one, it finds an empty list. Does anyone have an easy solution to make the for loop wait for the second call to finish?

Comment: Im going to try a recursive solution that calls itself at the end after the second call.

Comment: Okay the recursive solution worked! :)))))